# New Files on USB Drive Have Full Write Permissions

Tags: permissions, usb-drive

When I create a new file on my removable drive (flash drive), it is created with write permissions for everyone (`-rwxrwxrwx`). This also happens when I copy a file to the drive that didn't originally have such permissions.

I don't recall this being the default behavior. Is something configured wrong on my drive?

Answer (score 0):

Flash drives tend to be formatted as FAT32 which does not support user permissions.

Type

```
sudo blkid
```

in a terminal, and each drive will have an entry TYPE='something', if the drive shows 'vfat' then that would be the reason.

Comment: Running `blkid` produces `TYPE="ntfs"`.

Comment: Just found this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition. I think it answers my question